# רִבּוֹן כָּל הָעוֹלָמִים אֲדוֹן כָּל הַנְּשָׁמוֹת אֲדוֹן הַשָּׁלוֹם - source of this Shabbat prayer

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, shabbat, history

[Here](https://opensiddur.org/prayers/solilunar/shabbat/qabbalat-shabbat/master-of-the-cosmos-tehinah-entering-shabbat-rabbi-yitshaq-luria/) is its entry in the [open siddur project](https://opensiddur.org/).

The open siddur project demonstrates that the claim that this was composed by Rabbi Joseph of Rashkow, Posen can't be true as it is found in the siddur Tikunei Shabbat from 1614, before his time. The Tikunei Shabbat siddur is seemingly a posthumous work of Rabbi Yitzchak Luria (the Arizal), or perhaps from the school of the Ari.

I remember my father or grandmother telling me that back in Aden, they would say this prayer on Friday night. It seems that the history of this prayer is still an area of research and therefore I'd like to ask on Mi Yodeya if anyone has any further information about who composed this prayer, and what was the reason for its composition?

I do note that it contains a lot of supplications, and [we generally avoid praying for physical needs on Shabbat](https://aish.com/personal-prayers-on-shabbat/) (see Taanit 19a; Bava Batra 91a; Yerushalmi, Shabbat 15:3 etc), so I would be curious to find out if there is any resolution between that as well.

Basically, I am looking for any information on the origins and meaning of this prayer.

Comment: See Yaakov Jaffe's excellent article in the just published volume of Hakirah. The short short short version is this prayer is the original continuation of Shalom Aleichem and they were never intended to be split.

Comment: Second result: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D7%A8%D6%B4%D7%91%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9F+%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9C+%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%A2%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9C%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%93%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9F+%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9C+%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%A0%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B8%D7%9E%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA+%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%93%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9F+%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%A9%D6%BC%D7%81%D6%B8%D7%9C%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9D&sca_esv=583785414&biw=1488&bih=742&sxsrf=AM9HkKmuVCE9Nsewf07LiPa75L_SxnKYkA%3A1700401630597&source=lnt&tbs=bkt%3Ab%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1700&tbm=bks

Comment: @DoubleAA vol 34? Not sure I can get this in the UK. The GRAPKE - what are you trying to show me? Second result for me is a google book of a siddur for the 17th century with the prayer. I don't see any information about it though

Comment: All Hakirah articles are free in full on their website after the next volume is released. So if you don't want to pay you can just wait ~6 months. You could probably email R Jaffe directly, I bet he'd be happy to chat about the topic. Most people who bother writing articles on a given topic are.